# How to Increase the accuracy of pocketsphinxcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Guys, i've got a project going that uses the openEars API.Ive got it working on the device, but now the accuracy seems to be on the down low,say 1 out 50. I went through the source but am not getting any leads on how to improve it?Theres just one question in their support forum, but that refers to accuracy  on the simulator.For me the events such as startlistening etc are not even being called in the simulator.But on the device its ok. Just need to improve the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late here; just noticed that developers post OpenEars questions on Stack Overflow every once in a while. Between the accuracy rate and the idiosyncratic behavior on the simulator it sounds more like a project configuration issue than a Pocketsphinx issue to me.

If you are still experiencing this issue, please feel welcome to post about it on the [OpenEars forums](http://www.politepix.com/forums) so I can help troubleshoot it in-depth. I'd also recommend trying [0.91](http://www.politepix.com/openears) that just went up since it has overhauled install instructions for XCode 4, and a re-install might let you troubleshoot the issue on your own. It also has improved accuracy, but IMO a 2% accuracy rate is very likely to be a 0% accuracy rate with a red herring of some kind (for instance the language model that you want to use has a single word in common with the language model that OpenEars is actually linking to), so I doubt that the accuracy improvement will fix your 2% accuracy issue.

Disclaimer: OpenEars is my project, links above are to my site.